# How to retrieve the list of scheduled jobs in a job queue?

Tags: ibm-midrange, job-queue

I am assigned with a task to check if a job is currently present in a job queue as scheduled job. The matching criteria is the name of the job - as long as the job name matches the specified one then it counts. So is there any simple way to return the list of scheduled jobs in a give job queue? Or is there any better way to accomplish my task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [QUSLJOB](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fqusljob.htm) API will allow you to retrieve this information.

There is more information in [Chapter 13: Work Management APIs](http://bit.ly/vZhPdM) of the book [APIs at work](http://bit.ly/zMNQJ2).

[image: APIs at work]

Comment: How to use a user space? I have never tried that before. Can you give me some examples?

Comment: QUSLJOB example: http://www.lovelady.com/api-samp/?id=3  Be sure to read the API documentation in the manual so you can start to learn how to match up the documentation to RPG examples.  The documentation is generally written for the C programmer, so you'll need to translate the data types...